# symfony / webpack-encore: How can I make colors in .scss to come from an ENV var? What caches have to be rebuilt?

Tags: symfony, webpack, sass, environment-variables, webpack-encore

I have a project based on on symfony 5 and webpack-encore.

I run multiple instances of the project in production, with different contents. I create a docker image and run many containers off the same image, setting the content via ENV variables that typically configure the database name. No `.env.*` files involved, just RAM-based ENV vars.

The stylesheet is identical for all the clones. But now I would like to "tune" the base colors of the SASS from which all the color palette is derived from an ENV var.

In my `styles/app.scss` I do now have this line:

```
$primary: darken(#428bca, 20%);
```

1. How could I make `#428bca` to depend on the runtime docker environment variable that I set when running the container?
2. How can I call an env-var value from the .scss?
3. After changing it, is it enough to run only `yarn encore production` again? Or do I have to run the `php bin/console cache:clear` before running the `yarn encore`?

Answer (score 3):

You may be able to do it by using the sass-loader's `additionalData` option. See https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass-loader#additionaldata

You can pass the sass-loader options to `Encore.enableSassLoader()`, so I guess something like the following in webpack.config.js should create a `$main-color` SASS variable dynamically from your environment variable.

```js
Encore.enableSassLoader({
  additionalData: "$main-color: " + process.env.MAIN_COLOR + ";",
})
```

Then in your SASS code, you should be able to do `$primary: darken($main-color, 20%);`